# Drupal 8 - url rewrite don't work on beta12 after installation

Tags: 8

I don't have this problem on Drupal Beta 11, but with Beta 12, after installation, urls don't work, example :

**The requested URL /Beta12/admin/structure was not found on this server.**

Why I have this bug please ? It's a Drupal 12 problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try clearing all caches?

Comment: I can't without admin access.

Comment: Sure you can. Use either drush in the command-line, or manually delete your `/sites/default/files/php` folder and clear every database table starting with `cache_`  (do not delete them). If you still get a white screen afterwards, check the php_error.log

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but same problem after cache clear.

Comment: Well then, did you read my last comment till the end? What's in the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last Drupal 8 Beta release don't have .htaccess.